# Is it possible to change the contents of an iFrame from a Link on Another Page?

Tags: javascript, iframe, linker

I would like to have the contents of an iFrame that I created on one page change based upon the link that is clicked by the user on another page.  Is this possible to do with PHP or Javascript?  I know next to nothing about either, so any suggestions would be helpful.  Thank you in advance for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

[get opened pages/tabs with mootools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419177/get-opened-pages-tabs-with-mootools) Unfortunately it doesn't appear viable in javascript for security reasons (see link) and php is server-side so that won't be of any use

Comment: What about HTML5 with Sessionstorage or Localstorage?